# How do I know which type of authentication Active Directory is using?

Tags: web-services, active-directory, kerberos, ntlm, event-viewer

I've been trying to connect to a web service using Active Directory credentials and on the server side this is what the event viewer shows:

```
08/06/2014 05:50:39 p.m. An account failed to log on.

Subject:
                Security ID:               NULL SID
                Account Name:              -
                Account Domain:            -
                Logon ID:                  0x0

Logon Type:                                3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
                Security ID:               NULL SID
                Account Name:              VALIDUSER-REDACTED
                Account Domain:            VALIDDOMAIN-REDACTED

Failure Information:
                Failure Reason:            Unknown user name or bad password.
                Status:                    0xc000006d
                Sub Status:                0xc0000064

Process Information:
                Caller Process ID:         0x0
                Caller Process Name:       -

Network Information:
                Workstation Name:          WORKSTATION-REDACTED
                Source Network Address:    123.456.789.012
                Source Port:               1234

Detailed Authentication Information:
                Logon Process:             NtLmSsp 
                Authentication Package:    NTLM
                Transited Services:        -
                Package Name (NTLM only):  -
                Key Length:                0
```

I'm able to authenticate and send successful requests using the same credentials via browser, but unable to do so using a client. According to the event log I'm sending an "Unknown user name or bad password" but it's the same information I'm using to test the web service via browser.

I'm trying to send these requests using NTLM authentication; is there a way to know if I should use NTLMv1, NTLMv2, Kerberos or other type of authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to authenticate via browser, and used Fiddler to capture the authorization details, as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597573/how-to-find-if-ntlm-or-kerberos-is-used-from-www-authenticate-negotiate-header).